# How can I zoom into a ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to zoom and pan on an Image in SwiftUI for a Catalyst app. There is no PanGesture, but ScrollView seems to work well on both iPad and Mac.  I just can't scroll around on the magnified image.

```
struct TestScrollView: View {
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView([.horizontal,.vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
                    Image("image")
                        .resizable()
            }
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged({ (scale) in
                self.scale = scale
            }))
                .scaleEffect(self.scale)
        }
    }
}
```

And with the following code...

```
ScrollView([.horizontal,.vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
    Image("large_image")
        .resizable()
        .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged({ (scale) in
                        self.scale = scale
                    }))
        .scaleEffect(self.scale)
}
```

...I get this:

[image: test video]

It seems to scroll right a lot and it gets cut off on the left side.

Comment: I got the same results. Any update to this answer?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the content's frame size stays the same after applying `scaleEffect`, and that's why you are unable to scroll inside `ScrollView`. There's nowhere to scroll to. You can fix the problem by manually specifying the frame size after scaling. If you don't know the original frame size, use `GeometryReader` to calculate the frame size after scaling dynamically.

```
ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
    Image(systemName: "square.fill")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .scaleEffect(self.scale)
        .frame(
            width: 200 * self.scale,
            height: 200 * self.scale
        )
}
.gesture(magnificationGesture)
```

Also, your `MagnificationGesture`'s `onChanged` implementation has some problems. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341820/isnt-there-an-easy-way-to-pinch-to-zoom-in-an-image-in-swiftui/58468234#58468234) by James.