# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable ScrollView is not zooming

Tags: swiftui, zooming, uiviewrepresentable, swiftui-scrollview

I am developing an iOS app using the SwiftUI. I need to implement the "pinch to zoom" feature in the app so i tried using the SwiftUI's ScrollView but went in to the problems of not able to pinch and drag the content at the same time as discussed in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341820/isnt-there-an-easy-way-to-pinch-to-zoom-in-an-image-in-swiftui). So i tried using the UIKit's `UIScrollView` in an `UIViewRepresentable` as suggested in the same thread. The problem i am facing now is when i pinch zoom the view the following error is displayed in the console and view doesn't zoom.

```
[Assert] -[UIScrollView _clampedZoomScale:allowRubberbanding:]: Must be called with non-zero scale
```

My `UIViewRepresentable` does not occupy the entire screen and is embedded in a `VStack` that occupies some portion on the screen along with other elements. I am using `NavigationView` that holds the VStack. I have an `ObservableObject` as a state on the main view. I update few `@Published` properties on this `ObservableObject` from `.onAppear()` of the main view. When i stop updating these properties, the zoom seems to be working as expected. I am not sure what is causing the issue, can some one please help if you have faced the above error? Thanks in advance.

I could replicate this with a sample code provided below.

TestScrollViewApp.swift

```
@main
struct TestScrollViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView(interactor: TestInteractor())
        }
    }
}
```

TestView.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var interactor : TestInteractor
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    Text("Hi there!")
                    HStack{
                        Text("HI i am beside map")
                        NativeScrollView()
                    }
                    Text("Hi I am footer!")
                }
            }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }.onAppear{
                interactor.setUp()
        }
    }
}

struct NativeScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        let parent: NativeScrollView
        var zoomableView: UIView?

        init(_ parent: NativeScrollView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return zoomableView
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true;
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        //add the image view
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "mapscreen")
        scrollView.addSubview(imageview)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        return scrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.zoomableView = imageview
    }
}
```

TestInteractor.swift

```
class TestInteractor:ObservableObject{
    @Published var hasFooter = true
    
    func setUp(){
        hasFooter = false
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at SwiftUI's native [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview) - pretty sure that supports zoom. To learn more about zooming with a `ScrollView`, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884288/how-can-i-zoom-into-a-scrollview-in-swiftui).

Comment: For anyone that comes here trying to get well-working pan and zoom behavior of a UIImage in SwiftUI, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818140/1766265).