# How can I create smooth zooming and dragging navigation for an image in SwiftUI (similar to the zooming and panning capabilities in iPhone photos)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

In my app that I am building using SwiftUI, after the user selects an image from their camera roll, the selected image appears on the screen, and the user can zoom into this image and pan to different parts of it.  At the moment, parts of the image go offscreen despite my attempts to implement constraints, and after the user has zoomed in, they cannot pan to the sides of the image as it would conflict with the restraints.  How can I make this image view user freindly in a manner similar to viewing a photo in an iPhone's photo library?  Also, the image currently moves at a strange speed when dragged, so if I could also find out how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

The gestures in the following code are both applied to the image in question (selectedWallImage) elsewhere in the code.

```
    @State private var selectedWallImage: UIImage?
    @State private var scale = 1.0
    @State private var lastScale = 1.0
    private let minScale = 1.0
    private let maxScale = 5.0
    @State var isDragging = false
    @State var selectedWallPosition = CGSize.zero
    
    
    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { state in
                adjustScale(from: state)
            }
            .onEnded { state in
                withAnimation {
                    validateScaleLimits()
                }
                lastScale = 1.0
            }
    }
    
    var wallDrag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ value in
                withAnimation {
                    let deltaX = value.location.x - value.startLocation.x
                    let deltaY = value.location.y - value.startLocation.y

                    let reductionFactor: CGFloat = 1 / scale
                    let newPosition = CGSize(width: selectedWallPosition.width + deltaX * reductionFactor,
                                             height: selectedWallPosition.height + deltaY * reductionFactor)
                    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
                    
                    let xOffset = max(min(newPosition.width, screenSize.width * 0.25), screenSize.width * -0.25)
                    let yOffset = max(min(newPosition.height, screenSize.height * 0.25), screenSize.height * -0.25)
                    
                    selectedWallPosition = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: yOffset)
                }
                isDragging = true
            })
            .onEnded({ value in
                isDragging = false
            })
    }

// ...

//Functions used for scaling

    func adjustScale(from state: MagnificationGesture.Value) {
        let delta = state / lastScale
        scale *= delta
        lastScale = state
    }
    func getMinimumScaleAllowed() -> CGFloat {
        return max(scale, minScale)
    }
    func getMaximumScaleAllowed() -> CGFloat {
        return min(scale, maxScale)
    }
    func validateScaleLimits() {
        scale = getMinimumScaleAllowed()
        scale = getMaximumScaleAllowed()
    }
```

Comment: This one kind of works. Dragging is not smooth though https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411712/2528850